# Word пишет, что второе предложение не согласовано

Tags: стилистика

Гераса – один из городов Декаполиса . В десятку входили: Филадельфия (Амман), Гадара, Пелла, Абила, – находящиеся на территории современной Иордании, а также ряд населенных пунктов, расположенные ныне в Сирии и Израиле.

Comment: Это игра какая-то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...ряд населённых пунктов, (*каких?*) расположенн**ых** ныне...

Кроме того, из предложения необходимо убрать слово РЯД и заменить его, например, на НЕСКОЛЬКО:

***Гераса – один из городов Декаполиса . В десятку входили: Филадельфия (Амман), Гадара, Пелла и Абила, находящиеся на территории современной Иордании, а также несколько населенных пунктов, расположенных ныне в Сирии и Израиле.***

Вероятно, компьютер после словосочетания РЯД НАСЕЛЁННЫХ ПУНКТОВ требует причастия, относящегося к слову РЯД, которое является главным в с/с (причастия в форме РАСПОЛОЖЕННЫЙ, а не РАСПОЛОЖЕННЫХ). Если заменить РЯД на НЕСКОЛЬКО, всё меняется.  В этом случае согласование восстанавливается.

Comment: Это не помогает: все равно не согласовано.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, я дополнила ответ.

Comment: Заменил. Все в порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Гераса – один из городов Декаполиса . В десятку входили **Филадельфия (Амман), Гадара, Пелла и Абила, находящиеся на территории современной Иордании,** а также ряд населенных пунктов, расположенных ныне в Сирии и Израиле.

Comment: Поправил, но, по прежнему "не согласовано". Может быть, программа не распознает незнакомые слова?

Comment: Попробуйте подставить перед перечнем слово "города,  а потом просто  уберите перечень, чтобы посмотреть, на что реагирует программа.

Comment: Если добавить "города" - тогда все в порядке.